# Why is this procedure not returning values?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here is my code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fillHist_station
AS
    *--filling the cursor*
    CURSOR cur_newTab IS(
        SELECT s.NUM_STATION, extract (year from r.DATER), cl.NB_RESERV, SUM(p.MONTANT)
        FROM STATION s, HOTEL h, CHAMBRE c, RESERVATION r, CLIENTS cl, PAYEMENT p 
        WHERE s.NUM_STATION=h.NUM_STATION and h.NUM_HOTEL=c.NUM_HOTEL and c.IDCHAMBRE=r.IDCHAMBRE and r.NUMC=cl.NUMC and cl.NUMC=p.NUMC
        GROUP BY s.NUM_STATION, extract (year from r.DATER), cl.NB_RESERV);
                    V_numStation STATION.NUM_STATION%TYPE;
                    V_anne VARCHAR2(4);
                    V_nbreserve CLIENTS.NB_RESERV%TYPE;
                    V_revenu NUMBER(5);
                BEGIN
                    OPEN cur_newTab;
                    LOOP
*--fetching the values from the cursor in my variables*
                        FETCH cur_newTab INTO V_numStation, V_anne, V_nbreserve, V_revenu;
                                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_numStation||' '||V_anne||' '||V_nbreserve||' '||V_revenu);
                        EXIT WHEN cur_newTab%notfound;
*--inserting the values of the variables in a new table that i just created*
                        INSERT INTO HIST_STATION ("NUM_STATION","ANNEE","NB_RESERV","REVENU") VALUES(V_numStation,V_anne,V_nbreserve,V_revenu);
*--showing the values of the variables in the dbms output to see my results*
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_numStation||' '||V_anne||' '||V_nbreserve||' '||V_revenu);
                    END LOOP;
                    CLOSE cur_newTab;
                END fillHist_station;
                /
                SHOW ERRORS;
```

And there is no errors detected. Here's the script output:

```
    Procedure FILLHIST_STATION compiled

        No errors.
```

The only problem is that in my dbms output I'm not getting any results
and the new table is still empty.

and here is what should appear:

```
2   2018    6   1400
2   2017    1   2800
2   2018    3   8800
5   2018    2   1000
5   2018    1   950
3   2019    1   2800
2   2019    6   1400
2   2018    5   1550
3   2018    5   1550
3   2018    1   2800
1   2018    4   2300
5   2018    4   1300
```

Comment: Have you actually executed the procedure - or only compiled it? i.e. have you done `exec fillHist_station;`?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: So does the query return any rows?

Comment: Try adding a commit to your procedure?

Answer (score 1):

I am hoping you need to move the variable (V_*) into Declare section.

Try first printing the values from cursor record to ensure cursor is working fine.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fillHist_station
AS
*--filling the cursor*
CURSOR cur_newTab IS(
    SELECT s.NUM_STATION,extract (year from r.DATER),cl.NB_RESERV,SUM(p.MONTANT)
       FROM STATION s, HOTEL h, CHAMBRE c, RESERVATION r, CLIENTS cl, PAYEMENT p 
       WHERE s.NUM_STATION=h.NUM_STATION and h.NUM_HOTEL=c.NUM_HOTEL and c.IDCHAMBRE=r.IDCHAMBRE and r.NUMC=cl.NUMC and cl.NUMC=p.NUMC
       GROUP BY s.NUM_STATION, extract (year from r.DATER), cl.NB_RESERV);
BEGIN
  FOR cur_newTab_rec  IN cur_newTab
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cur_newTab_rec.NUM_STATION);
  END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_newTab;
END fillHist_station;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Comment: Not sure why you would need to `set serveroutput on` in order to compile a procedure.

Comment: I agree a cursor FOR loop makes a lot more sense here, assuming a loop is needed at all.